# How can I use methods from a different class in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods, banking

I tried searching this question but couldn't find anything that really helped me..

I have a Java file which contains a bank account class with methods to deposit to, withdraw from, change the name on, charge a service fee to, and print a summary of the account. This file is called Account.java

When I try to run this program, I get a message saying no main methods found in the file.

So then I also have another file called ManageAccount.java which is supposed to use Account class to create and manage 2 different bank accounts. This file only has the instructions (in comment form) and only 3 lines of code which my professor included:

```
    public class ManageAccounts { 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Account acct1, acct2;
```

I'm confused on how to link the two files together. On the ManageAccount file, I added these 2 lines at the beginning:

```
    package Account; 
    import Account.*;
```

What do I do? How can I use the withdraw, deposit, changeName, serviceFee, and printSummary methods from my Account class in my ManageAccounts class?

Comment: If it is a static method, call it through the class: OtherClass.callMethod()', if it is an instance method, call it through an instance: OtherClass o = new OtherClass(); o.callMethod();'

Comment: Post your relevant code please.

Comment: `no main methods found in the file`: I assume, that you try to start class `Account`which has no main method.

Comment: Yes, Account has no main method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a look on basics of oop. Than In your main method create two new instances of account by new.

```
  public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Account acct1 = new Account(1000,"Sally",1111); 
    Account acct2 = new Account(1000,"Barry",1112);
    acct1.depositTo(2000);

}
```

In your variables acct1 and acct2 you have two instances of Account class. Account class is some kind of shape for your instances. On instances you can call your defined methods. If you want to run your program you have to run it on class where the main method is defined.

Comment: I fixed my ManageAccounts file with all the deposits and withdrawals I was supposed to do. But I am getting this error: ManageAccounts.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
   Account acct1 = new Account(1000, "Sally", 1111);
   ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class ManageAccounts

Answer (score 1):

To be able to start a Java program you need some code to start from. That is the main method. Here is a example how it can look.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Of course this main method does nothing. So you need to insert your code in the method. You also need to keep in mind that to be able to call the method you need to create a instance of the class you want to use (unless the method is static) Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/ to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer the question since you didn't post all of the code and your error message.
If order for class A to be able to use class B's methods, class B needs to be set in the build path of the class A's project. The easiest thing for you would be to place them in the same package, so they would be visible to each other (assuming the method's aren't private.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not cleared with the basics itself so first read the concepts of OPPS and get started so that u can avoid errors in future .To access methods in other class , instance is created and corresponding methods can be accessed using it .  Check the below example for you understanding ..

```
public class Account {
int id;
Date dateCreated;
double balance, annualInteretRate;
// Other fields

public Account() {
// Here is where you create a default account.
}

public void setID(int i) {
id = i;
}

public int getID() {
return id;
}

// Method that checks to see if balance is sufficient for withdrawal.
// If so, reduces balance by amount; if not, prints message.
public void withdraw(double amount)
{
if (balance >= amount)
{
balance -= amount;
}
else
{
System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
}
}

// Method that adds deposit amount to balance.
public void deposit(double amount)
{
balance += amount;
}
//-----------------------------------…
// Returns balance.
//-----------------------------------…
public double getBalance()
{
return balance;
}
// Adds interest to the account and returns the new balance.
/
public double addInterest ()
{
balance += (balance * RATE);
return balance;
}
```

/// Main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankProgram {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Account acct1 = new Account();
acct1.setID(1122);
acct1.setBalance(20000);
acct1.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);
System.out.print("\nDepositing $3000 into account, balance is now ");
acct1.deposit(3000);
System.out.println(acct.getBalance());
System.out.print("\nWithdrawing $2500, balance is now ");
acct1.withdraw(2500);
System.out.println(acct.getBalance());
}
}
```